# How can I loop variables with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, variables

I'm new with Javascript and Jquery and I'm facing a small problem.

I'm trying to make sure that if a given link exists, hovering over this link will bring up a popup with the fadeToggle().

So I wrote this code that works:

```
  if ($('.link-1')) {
    $('.link-1').mouseover(function () {
      $('.popup-1').fadeToggle();
    })
      .mouseout(function () {
        $('.popup-1').fadeToggle();
      })
  }
```

But, instead of repeating it ten times, I wanted to write a loop, like this:

```
  var number = 0;
  while (number < 10) {
    var popup = '.popup-' + number;
    var link = '.link-' + number;
    if ($(link)) {
      $(link).mouseover(function () {
        $(popup).fadeToggle();
      })
        .mouseout(function () {
          $(popup).fadeToggle();
        })
    }
    number++;
  }
```

But it does not work. Could you help me please ?

I thank you in advance !

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do ten times?

Comment: I'm trying to repeat this action 10 times (show my div with the ".popup-1" class when user hover my div with ".link-1" class, same for ".link-2" and ".popup-2", etc ...)

Comment: This might seems to work but will not work. Is this working fine for the last element i.e.,when `number` is `9` ?

Comment: Is the end goal to make a tooltip? If so, jquery has some baked in, just add a title attribute to each anchor tag,(i.e. <a title='this text would show on hover'>Tool tip</a>) and add $(document).tooltip() in your script. If you are looking to launch a custom popup while hovering over each link, you might be better off using a data attribute on the links and tying them to their respective popups, then launching the event on a common class name (something like ".hasPopUp"). Are you generating the links statically or dynamically?

Comment: @JoshSchindele Not really. I want to display an image, located in a div .popup-"..." relative to an article. The links are generated dynamically by incrementing variable $number in the PHP code (I use wordpress). I use this var like that : link-<?php echo $number ?> and popup-<?php echo $number ?> In this way, the link of the article and my image are matching. Do you have any documentation for this use of "data attribute?"

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal It doesn't work. Using console.log("popup") and console.log("link") in the loop gave me link-1, popup-1 ... until 10 but the desired effect does not occur !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, I'd recommend this approach.

Add a data attribute to each link that corresponds with the popup you want to fire. This will look something like this:

```
<a href='#' class='link-1' data-popup='popup-1'> Link </a>
```

Then add a hover event to ALL links, that performs an action if it has the data type:

```
//hover event on all links(assumes anchor tags)   
    $('a').mouseover(function () {
      if ($(this).attr('data-popup')) {
     let popup = '.' + $(this).attr('data-popup');
        $(`${popup}`).fadeToggle();
    }})
      .mouseout(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('data-popup')) {
        let popup = '.' + $(this).attr('data-popup');
        $(`${popup}`).fadeToggle();
      }})
```

You could also make this a single line function using .hover instead of .mouseover and .mouseout if it fits your use case

**refactoring process is added here:

```
//start with the original function

$('a').hover(function () {
  if ($(this).attr('data-popup')) {
  let popup = '.' + $(this).attr('data-popup');
    $(`${popup}`).fadeToggle();
}})

//consolidate the enter and exit events using .hover()

$('a').hover(function () {
  if ($(this).attr('data-popup')) {
  let popup = '.' + $(this).attr('data-popup');
    $(`${popup}`).fadeToggle();
}})

//remove the if statement, because the function firing without a pop up won't result in any effect

$('a').hover(function () {
  let popup = '.' + $(this).attr('data-popup');
    $(`${popup}`).fadeToggle();
})

//substitute the variable directly into the jquery tag

$('a').hover(function () {
    $(`'.${$(this).attr('data-popup')}`).fadeToggle();
})

// use an ES6 arrow function to make this a one line function

$('a').hover(() =>  $(`.${$(this).attr('data-popup')}`).fadeToggle())

//as is, this function won't work, because the arrow function binds the "this" keyword differently. 
//Event handlers have an optional parameter that is an event JSON object, so we pass that into the function.
//Because it is a parameter, and is used as a variable we can call event "e" for short
//target is a property of the JSON object 'event' that indicates what specific element is triggering the event
// You can console log "e" to see what other values are baked into the event 


$('a').hover((e) => $(`.${$(e.target).attr('data-popup')}`).fadeToggle())

//lastly, because we are using an anonymous arrow function with only one parameter, we can omit the parenthesis around the paremeter

$('a').hover(e => $(`.${$(e.target).attr('data-popup')}`).fadeToggle())
```

The end result is the one liner below!

```
$('a').hover(e => $(`.${$(e.target).attr('data-popup')}`).fadeToggle())
```

Additional info on data attributes can be found here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: Hi, 

Looks better but still doesn't works. However it's seems very close ! Logs returns to me : " Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ".popup-3" " for example when .link-3 is fired.

In the same way, using "(".link-1").attr('data-popup')" gives me the corresponding popup class (.popup-1)

Indeed, I was not aware with the use of data attribute and looks quite easy and more fitted for what i want to do :-)

Comment: @innocent-musica I've revised the sample to build the class then inject it using template literals, that should fix it for you! If you are not copying and pasting and unfamiliar with template literals, make sure you are using the back ticks " ` " in the jquery selector

Comment: The simplest the best! The single line works like a charm, despite the fact that the first solution you gived to me do not work! Can you explain to me how this line work? (does not understand the use of "e" and "e.target" ... Thanks you !!

Comment: @innocent-musica Certainly. The explanation is too long to add as a comment, so i'll add the refactoring in as an edit above

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the web community :-)

My jQuery skills are a bit rusty, but I recall, that there is an [Attribute Contains Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/), which you could combine with [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) like so:

```
$('[class*="link-"]').each(function (index, link) {
  $('[class="popup-"' + index + '"]').each(function (_, popup) {
    $(link)
      .mouseover(function () {
        $(popup).fadeToggle();
      })
      .mouseout(function () {
        $(popup).fadeToggle();
      })
  }
}
```

The second index is not interesting, that's why I named the argument „_”.
Let me know, whether it still works

Comment: It doesn't work :-( I've replaced my code by yours but It's gave me an error : Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [class="popup-"0"]. In addition to that, the code seems to look after the .popup-0 but my links begins with 1.

Comment: Ah, okay. Now I see my mistake. Sorry!
`$('[class="popup-' + index + '"]')` will make the Syntax Error go away (notice the removed double quote after `popup-`).
If you replace `"popup-' + index` with `popup-' + (index + 1)` (including round braces), the `popup-` should start with 1 as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your objects are in order from link-1 to link-10, you can try this method

1. Loop object that has class "link-[number]" using each function
2. save number using index + 1
3. give action to object that have been hovered

so the code will be like this:

```
$('[class*="link-"]').each(function (index) {
    var number = index + 1; //index start from 0, so it need to add + 1
    $(this)
        .mouseover(function () {
            $('[class="popup-' + number+ '"]').fadeToggle();
        })
        .mouseout(function () {
            $('[class="popup-' + number+ '"]').fadeToggle();
        })
});
```

But if your object are not in order from link-1 to link-10, I recommend to use custom data attribute in your HTML code.
Example:

```
<a class="link-1" data-number="1">test 1</a>
<div class="popup-1" style="display:none">
test 1 popup
</div>
```

Then change number variable to this code:

```
var number = $(this).attr("data-number");
```

It will more save.
Hope it helps.